# Configurations needed for unattended-upgrades to run indefinitely?

Tags: grub2, updates, amazon-ec2, unattended-upgrades

What disk space and other configurations are needed so that you can trust `unattended-upgrades` to run unattended more or less indefinitely? I'm asking this to try to understand what went wrong with a particular server.

In early 2014 I setup an Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS system on Amazon EC2 (using ami-c45f6281), enabling unattended-upgrades to maintain security updates.  Then I let it be.

Looking in the logs, I can see that On 2015-05-20, unattended-upgrades fell over, apparently because of lack of disk space. This seems to be the key line from the log file `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg_2015-05-20_06:54:02.822902.log`:

```
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.2.0-84-virtual.
Unpacking linux-headers-3.2.0-84-virtual (from .../linux-headers-3.2.0-84-virtual_3.2.0-84.121_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-84-virtual_3.2.0-84.121_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 error creating symbolic link `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-84-virtual/include/linux/nfs2.h': No space left on device
```

In the days after that, all I see is this over and over again from then until now:

```
2015-11-02 06:28:44,233 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2015-11-02 06:28:44,249 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2015-11-02 06:28:44,256 INFO Allowed origins are: ['o=Ubuntu,a=precise-security']
2015-11-02 06:29:09,126 ERROR Cache has broken packages, exiting
```

But this initial error confuses me because `df` seems to indicate I have over 1 GB of disk space free:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-27-132:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  5.7G  1.8G  77% /
udev            288M   12K  287M   1% /dev
tmpfs            60M  196K   59M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            296M     0  296M   0% /run/shm
```

This may be related to the [this bug with the grub bootloader on EC2 instances](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-init/+bug/1336855), but that bug describes instances not even booting properly after an update, a very alarming prospect which now has me frightened to even try rebooting.

More generally, I'm wondering if Ubuntu and unattended-upgrades is actually a sensible way to build a "set it and forget it" sort of system. Maybe that idea was naive, and the right way to do this is instead to shut off updates and try to minimize attack surface, or to choose a more server-oriented distro?

Comment: For anyone coming along later with a similar question or a similar problem, I discovered that unattended-upgrades failed here not because it ran out of disk space but because it ran of inodes. It ran out of inodes because it never erased uninstalled kernel updates. It never installed the kernel updates because it never restarted. It never restarted either because I did not explicitly configure it to do so, or else because I never installed mailx, so it could not email me to notify me it had restarted. TLDR: unattended-upgrades is not safe & reliable unless you know it very well.